# Type system: ANSI SQL (standard) vs. Postgres, Oracle, DB2

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ansi-sql

This is a pretty general question, and am looking to find an expert who is both familiar with the standard as well as a few DB systems. At a high-level, what are some of the differences between the type system as described in the SQL standard vs that implemented in Postgres, Oracle, or DB2.

I'm just making something up (**and it's incorrect** -- and just used to show the format of the type of comparison I'm interested in seeing), but an example might be along the lines of:

| Standard | Postgres | Oracle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `INTERVAL` type | Does not exist, closest is `TIME` | Same as standard. |

(As an aside, would this question be better for DBA?)

Comment: Postgres has an `interval` type:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know, I just meant the table format of how the dbs could be compared.

Comment: I would say "data types" is rather a topic for programmers, not for administrators (DBA); so the question probably belongs here, rather than on the DBA forum, even though it is not really a question about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few people will be able to give you a whole complete list, so I'll just tell you what I know, without any claim to completeness. I also restrict myself to the database I know better.

Comments to the database's implementation describe deviations from the standard.

| SQL standard | PostgreSQL | Oracle | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `CHARACTER` | ✔ | empty strings are treated as NULL | weird standard-dictated semantics; avoid |
| `CHARACTER VARYING` | ✔ | empty strings are treated as NULL |  |
| `CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT` | non-standard name `text` or `varchar` | ✔ |  |
| `NATIONAL CHARACTER` | ✔ | empty strings are treated as NULL | obsolescent |
| `NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING` | ✔ | empty strings are treated as NULL | obsolescent |
| `NATIONAL CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT` | non-standard name `text` or `varchar` | empty strings are treated as NULL | obsolescent |
| `BINARY LARGE OBJECT` | non-standard name `bytea` | ✔ |  |
| `NUMERIC` | ✔ | ✔ |  |
| `DECIMAL` | ✔ | ✔ | virtually the same as `NUMERIC` |
| `SMALLINT` | ✔ | ✔ (same type as `NUMERIC`) |  |
| `INTEGER` | ✔ | ✔ (same type as `NUMERIC`) |  |
| `BIGINT` | ✔ | ✔ (same type as `NUMERIC`) |  |
| `FLOAT` | ✔ | ✔ (same type as `NUMERIC`) |  |
| `REAL` | ✔ | ✔ (same type as `NUMERIC`, but there is also `BINARY_FLOAT`) |  |
| `DOUBLE PRECISION` | ✔ | (same type as `NUMERIC`, but there is also `BINARY_DOUBLE`) |  |
| `BOOLEAN` | ✔ | ❌ (but allowed in PL/SQL) |  |
| `DATE` | ✔ | is really a timestamp |  |
| `TIME` | ✔ | ❌ |  |
| `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` | ✔ | ❌ | semantics unclear; avoid |
| `TIMESTAMP` | ✔ | ✔ |  |
| `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` | semantics differ from the standard | ✔ |  |
| `INTERVAL` | ✔ | ✔ |  |
| `ROW` | composity types | object types |  |
| `REF` | ❌ | ✔ (non-standard syntax) |  |
| `<type> ARRAY` | ✔ | vararray types |  |
| `<type> MULTISET` | ❌ | ❌ |  |
| `XML` | ✔ | non-standard name `XMLTYPE` |  |

Comment: In Oracle pretty much all standard names for "numbers" (except float and double) are aliases for `NUMBER` with different scale and precision.

Comment: No, float and double are both `FLOAT` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0380b2b5bcf176b529242bc8071b70dc

Comment: They show up as `FLOAT`, yes. For some reason, I had the impression that they are the same under the hood, but I have no proof, and I cannot read up the code...

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. [The manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#SQLRF-GUID-10D4D073-866D-4BD4-B3E9-ED153D505A6A) states that "*The FLOAT data type is a subtype of NUMBER*"

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe great answer, a few questions here. (1) Possible to link to the definition, for example [`XMLTYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS369)? (2) How are the following defined in SQL Standard: `ROW`, `REF`, `MULTISET`, or even `ARRAY` ? For array does the standard allow something like `[1,2,'a']` or `[[1,2],[3,4]]` or `[1,2,null]` or how does it define 'array', as it seems to be a bit different every place I've looked (mysql vs bigquery vs postgres, etc.)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe finally, why is it suggested to avoid `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` ? I've seen that in a few dialects, such as Postgres, etc.

Comment: I think I already went out of my way to come up with that list. I cannot turn it into a master thesis on database data types. As for links, both databases have documentation where this information can be found under the chapter "data types". As for `time with time zone`: what time is `12:00:00 Europe/Vienna` (think of daylight savings time)?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for your time. I added a bounty to it as well.

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Data_types is pretty nice, to supplement this table.

Comment: This is wrong for Oracle `CLOB` data types; you can store either `NULL` for a null value or `EMPTY_CLOB()` for an empty string. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b87f5fc338aefe0b335b6681eed0c90f)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could you briefly explain the `REF` and `ROW` type, or link for those? I've never heard of those before.

Comment: Unfortunately the standard is not freely available, so I cannot link to it. The `REF` type is a reference to a table row, and the `ROW` type is a composite type.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe by reference do a table, do you mean like `REF` to the PK of a particular row or you mean a generic row ?

Comment: As far as I understood, it is a reference to the whole row.